# GDB: Follow exception flow

Tags: c++, exception, gdb

Consider the following MWE:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 2;

    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("Example");
        a = 4;
    } catch (const std::exception &) {
        a = 5;
    }

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

If I compile this with `g++ -g -O0 test.cpp` and then run the resulting binary through `gdb` via `gdb ./a.out` I can start stepping through the program. However, as soon as I reach the line that throws the exception inputting `next` or `step` does not lead me to the line `a = 5` but instead immediately prints 5 to the console and then gdb tells me that the process has exited normally.

This is quite annoying as oftentimes it would actually be useful to figure out where the thrown exception is handled.

Is there a way to get `gdb` to follow the full program flow even when exceptions are involved?

My GDB version is `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1`

---

EDIT: To ensure that the thrown exception has not been optimized out of my binary, I checked the respective assembly via `objdump` and if interpret that corretly, throwing the exception is still part of the binary:

```
objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out 

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000001000 <_init>:
    1000:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1004:       48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
    1008:       48 8b 05 d1 2f 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2fd1]        # 3fe0 <__gmon_start__@Base>
    100f:       48 85 c0                test   rax,rax
    1012:       74 02                   je     1016 <_init+0x16>
    1014:       ff d0                   call   rax
    1016:       48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
    101a:       c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000001020 <.plt>:
    1020:       ff 35 2a 2f 00 00       push   QWORD PTR [rip+0x2f2a]        # 3f50 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
    1026:       f2 ff 25 2b 2f 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2f2b]        # 3f58 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
    102d:       0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
    1030:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1034:       68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
    1039:       f2 e9 e1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    103f:       90                      nop
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1044:       68 01 00 00 00          push   0x1
    1049:       f2 e9 d1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    104f:       90                      nop
    1050:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1054:       68 02 00 00 00          push   0x2
    1059:       f2 e9 c1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    105f:       90                      nop
    1060:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1064:       68 03 00 00 00          push   0x3
    1069:       f2 e9 b1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    106f:       90                      nop
    1070:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1074:       68 04 00 00 00          push   0x4
    1079:       f2 e9 a1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    107f:       90                      nop
    1080:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1084:       68 05 00 00 00          push   0x5
    1089:       f2 e9 91 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    108f:       90                      nop
    1090:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1094:       68 06 00 00 00          push   0x6
    1099:       f2 e9 81 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    109f:       90                      nop
    10a0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    10a4:       68 07 00 00 00          push   0x7
    10a9:       f2 e9 71 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    10af:       90                      nop
    10b0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    10b4:       68 08 00 00 00          push   0x8
    10b9:       f2 e9 61 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    10bf:       90                      nop
    10c0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    10c4:       68 09 00 00 00          push   0x9
    10c9:       f2 e9 51 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    10cf:       90                      nop
    10d0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    10d4:       68 0a 00 00 00          push   0xa
    10d9:       f2 e9 41 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    10df:       90                      nop

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

00000000000010e0 <__cxa_finalize@plt>:
    10e0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    10e4:       f2 ff 25 cd 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ecd]        # 3fb8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    10eb:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

Disassembly of section .plt.sec:

00000000000010f0 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)@plt>:
    10f0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    10f4:       f2 ff 25 65 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e65]        # 3f60 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21>
    10fb:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001100 <__cxa_begin_catch@plt>:
    1100:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1104:       f2 ff 25 5d 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e5d]        # 3f68 <__cxa_begin_catch@CXXABI_1.3>
    110b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001110 <__cxa_allocate_exception@plt>:
    1110:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1114:       f2 ff 25 55 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e55]        # 3f70 <__cxa_allocate_exception@CXXABI_1.3>
    111b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001120 <__cxa_free_exception@plt>:
    1120:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1124:       f2 ff 25 4d 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e4d]        # 3f78 <__cxa_free_exception@CXXABI_1.3>
    112b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001130 <__cxa_atexit@plt>:
    1130:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1134:       f2 ff 25 45 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e45]        # 3f80 <__cxa_atexit@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    113b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001140 <std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@plt>:
    1140:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1144:       f2 ff 25 3d 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e3d]        # 3f88 <std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    114b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001150 <std::ios_base::Init::Init()@plt>:
    1150:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1154:       f2 ff 25 35 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e35]        # 3f90 <std::ios_base::Init::Init()@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    115b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001160 <__cxa_end_catch@plt>:
    1160:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1164:       f2 ff 25 2d 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e2d]        # 3f98 <__cxa_end_catch@CXXABI_1.3>
    116b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001170 <__cxa_throw@plt>:
    1170:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1174:       f2 ff 25 25 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e25]        # 3fa0 <__cxa_throw@CXXABI_1.3>
    117b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001180 <std::ostream::operator<<(int)@plt>:
    1180:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1184:       f2 ff 25 1d 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e1d]        # 3fa8 <std::ostream::operator<<(int)@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    118b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000001190 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>:
    1190:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1194:       f2 ff 25 15 2e 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e15]        # 3fb0 <_Unwind_Resume@GCC_3.0>
    119b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000011a0 <_start>:
    11a0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    11a4:       31 ed                   xor    ebp,ebp
    11a6:       49 89 d1                mov    r9,rdx
    11a9:       5e                      pop    rsi
    11aa:       48 89 e2                mov    rdx,rsp
    11ad:       48 83 e4 f0             and    rsp,0xfffffffffffffff0
    11b1:       50                      push   rax
    11b2:       54                      push   rsp
    11b3:       45 31 c0                xor    r8d,r8d
    11b6:       31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
    11b8:       48 8d 3d ca 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xca]        # 1289 <main>
    11bf:       ff 15 03 2e 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e03]        # 3fc8 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34>
    11c5:       f4                      hlt    
    11c6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00   cs nop WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

00000000000011d0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
    11d0:       48 8d 3d 49 2e 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x2e49]        # 4020 <__TMC_END__>
    11d7:       48 8d 05 42 2e 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x2e42]        # 4020 <__TMC_END__>
    11de:       48 39 f8                cmp    rax,rdi
    11e1:       74 15                   je     11f8 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>
    11e3:       48 8b 05 ee 2d 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2dee]        # 3fd8 <_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable@Base>
    11ea:       48 85 c0                test   rax,rax
    11ed:       74 09                   je     11f8 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>
    11ef:       ff e0                   jmp    rax
    11f1:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
    11f8:       c3                      ret    
    11f9:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000001200 <register_tm_clones>:
    1200:       48 8d 3d 19 2e 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x2e19]        # 4020 <__TMC_END__>
    1207:       48 8d 35 12 2e 00 00    lea    rsi,[rip+0x2e12]        # 4020 <__TMC_END__>
    120e:       48 29 fe                sub    rsi,rdi
    1211:       48 89 f0                mov    rax,rsi
    1214:       48 c1 ee 3f             shr    rsi,0x3f
    1218:       48 c1 f8 03             sar    rax,0x3
    121c:       48 01 c6                add    rsi,rax
    121f:       48 d1 fe                sar    rsi,1
    1222:       74 14                   je     1238 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
    1224:       48 8b 05 bd 2d 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2dbd]        # 3fe8 <_ITM_registerTMCloneTable@Base>
    122b:       48 85 c0                test   rax,rax
    122e:       74 08                   je     1238 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
    1230:       ff e0                   jmp    rax
    1232:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
    1238:       c3                      ret    
    1239:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000001240 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
    1240:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1244:       80 3d 05 2f 00 00 00    cmp    BYTE PTR [rip+0x2f05],0x0        # 4150 <completed.0>
    124b:       75 2b                   jne    1278 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x38>
    124d:       55                      push   rbp
    124e:       48 83 3d 62 2d 00 00 00         cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d62],0x0        # 3fb8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    1256:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    1259:       74 0c                   je     1267 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x27>
    125b:       48 8b 3d a6 2d 00 00    mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2da6]        # 4008 <__dso_handle>
    1262:       e8 79 fe ff ff          call   10e0 <__cxa_finalize@plt>
    1267:       e8 64 ff ff ff          call   11d0 <deregister_tm_clones>
    126c:       c6 05 dd 2e 00 00 01    mov    BYTE PTR [rip+0x2edd],0x1        # 4150 <completed.0>
    1273:       5d                      pop    rbp
    1274:       c3                      ret    
    1275:       0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
    1278:       c3                      ret    
    1279:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000001280 <frame_dummy>:
    1280:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1284:       e9 77 ff ff ff          jmp    1200 <register_tm_clones>

0000000000001289 <main>:
    1289:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    128d:       55                      push   rbp
    128e:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    1291:       41 55                   push   r13
    1293:       41 54                   push   r12
    1295:       53                      push   rbx
    1296:       48 83 ec 18             sub    rsp,0x18
    129a:       c7 45 d4 02 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x2c],0x2
    12a1:       bf 10 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x10
    12a6:       e8 65 fe ff ff          call   1110 <__cxa_allocate_exception@plt>
    12ab:       48 89 c3                mov    rbx,rax
    12ae:       48 8d 05 4f 0d 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0xd4f]        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    12b5:       48 89 c6                mov    rsi,rax
    12b8:       48 89 df                mov    rdi,rbx
    12bb:       e8 30 fe ff ff          call   10f0 <std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)@plt>
    12c0:       48 8b 05 09 2d 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d09]        # 3fd0 <std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    12c7:       48 89 c2                mov    rdx,rax
    12ca:       48 8d 05 4f 2a 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x2a4f]        # 3d20 <typeinfo for std::runtime_error@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    12d1:       48 89 c6                mov    rsi,rax
    12d4:       48 89 df                mov    rdi,rbx
    12d7:       e8 94 fe ff ff          call   1170 <__cxa_throw@plt>
    12dc:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    12e0:       49 89 c5                mov    r13,rax
    12e3:       49 89 d4                mov    r12,rdx
    12e6:       48 89 df                mov    rdi,rbx
    12e9:       e8 32 fe ff ff          call   1120 <__cxa_free_exception@plt>
    12ee:       4c 89 e8                mov    rax,r13
    12f1:       4c 89 e2                mov    rdx,r12
    12f4:       eb 04                   jmp    12fa <main+0x71>
    12f6:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    12fa:       48 83 fa 01             cmp    rdx,0x1
    12fe:       74 08                   je     1308 <main+0x7f>
    1300:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    1303:       e8 88 fe ff ff          call   1190 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>
    1308:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    130b:       e8 f0 fd ff ff          call   1100 <__cxa_begin_catch@plt>
    1310:       48 89 45 d8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],rax
    1314:       c7 45 d4 05 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x2c],0x5
    131b:       e8 40 fe ff ff          call   1160 <__cxa_end_catch@plt>
    1320:       8b 45 d4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x2c]
    1323:       89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
    1325:       48 8d 05 14 2d 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x2d14]        # 4040 <std::cout@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    132c:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    132f:       e8 4c fe ff ff          call   1180 <std::ostream::operator<<(int)@plt>
    1334:       48 8b 15 85 2c 00 00    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2c85]        # 3fc0 <std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    133b:       48 89 d6                mov    rsi,rdx
    133e:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    1341:       e8 fa fd ff ff          call   1140 <std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@plt>
    1346:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    134b:       48 83 c4 18             add    rsp,0x18
    134f:       5b                      pop    rbx
    1350:       41 5c                   pop    r12
    1352:       41 5d                   pop    r13
    1354:       5d                      pop    rbp
    1355:       c3                      ret    

0000000000001356 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)>:
    1356:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    135a:       55                      push   rbp
    135b:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    135e:       48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
    1362:       89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
    1365:       89 75 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],esi
    1368:       83 7d fc 01             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
    136c:       75 3b                   jne    13a9 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+0x53>
    136e:       81 7d f8 ff ff 00 00    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xffff
    1375:       75 32                   jne    13a9 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+0x53>
    1377:       48 8d 05 d3 2d 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x2dd3]        # 4151 <std::__ioinit>
    137e:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    1381:       e8 ca fd ff ff          call   1150 <std::ios_base::Init::Init()@plt>
    1386:       48 8d 05 7b 2c 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x2c7b]        # 4008 <__dso_handle>
    138d:       48 89 c2                mov    rdx,rax
    1390:       48 8d 05 ba 2d 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x2dba]        # 4151 <std::__ioinit>
    1397:       48 89 c6                mov    rsi,rax
    139a:       48 8b 05 4f 2c 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2c4f]        # 3ff0 <std::ios_base::Init::~Init()@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    13a1:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    13a4:       e8 87 fd ff ff          call   1130 <__cxa_atexit@plt>
    13a9:       90                      nop
    13aa:       c9                      leave  
    13ab:       c3                      ret    

00000000000013ac <_GLOBAL__sub_I_main>:
    13ac:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    13b0:       55                      push   rbp
    13b1:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    13b4:       be ff ff 00 00          mov    esi,0xffff
    13b9:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
    13be:       e8 93 ff ff ff          call   1356 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)>
    13c3:       5d                      pop    rbp
    13c4:       c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .fini:

00000000000013c8 <_fini>:
    13c8:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    13cc:       48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
    13d0:       48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
    13d4:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: Not reproduced on Fedora with GDB version `GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora Linux 12.1-6.fc37`.

Comment: Are you compiling using `-O0 -g` options? Otherwise code can get optimized and you will see weird behavior in GDB.

Comment: @kiner_shah yes I do

Comment: You can try to work around this problem with `catch catch` in gdb.

Comment: @ssbssa thanks, that works! However, does this mean that this is a known issue in gdb or is this just a workaround that you came up with based on my question?

Comment: Not sure if this is a known issue, it's just the first idea I had.